# Correctly deal with HTML encoding in ACCESS

Tags: html, ms-access, vba, encoding

Somebody sent me a program in which I would need to replace all characters that have special encoding in HTML with their encoded version (e.g. change all *'* to *'*, or all *À* to *À*).

I'm not sure why it's needed, but I don't make the decision and I have to do it. I was wondering if there was a way to quickly and efficiently replace all those characters at once or with the least amount of code possible.

To make thing more 'interesting' the whole thing is in ACCESS 2003.

I will probably do something like that

```
Private Function EncodeString(strOriginal as string) as string
'replace the characters with Replace or something of the sort.    

End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go, this should do what you need:

```
Private Function EncodeString(strOriginal as string) as string
    Dim strTemp as string
    strTemp = strOriginal
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "ó", "&oacute;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "á", "&aacute;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "é", "&eacute;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "í", "&iacute;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "ú", "&uacute;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "Á", "&Aacute;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "É", "&Eacute;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "Í", "&Iacute;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "Ó", "&Oacute;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "Ú", "&Uacute;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "¡", "&iexcl;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "¢", "&cent;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "£", "&pound;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "¤", "&curren;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "¥", "&yen;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "¦", "&brvbar;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "§", "&sect;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "¨", "&uml;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "©", "&copy;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "ª", "&ordf;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "«", "&laquo;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "¬", "&not;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "®", "&reg;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "¯", "&macr;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "°", "&deg;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "±", "&plusmn;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "²", "&sup2;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "³", "&sup3;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "´", "&acute;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "µ", "&micro;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "¶", "&para;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "·", "&middot;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "¸", "&cedil;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "¹", "&sup1;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "º", "&ordm;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "»", "&raquo;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "¼", "&frac14;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "½", "&frac12;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "¾", "&frac34;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "¿", "&iquest;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "×", "&times;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "÷", "&divide;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "À", "&Agrave;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "Â", "&Acirc;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "Ã", "&Atilde;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "Ä", "&Auml;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "Å", "&Aring;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "Æ", "&AElig;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "Ç", "&Ccedil;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "È", "&Egrave;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "Ê", "&Ecirc;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "Ë", "&Euml;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "Ì", "&Igrave;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "Î", "&Icirc;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "Ï", "&Iuml;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "Ð", "&ETH;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "Ñ", "&Ntilde;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "Ò", "&Ograve;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "Ô", "&Ocirc;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "Õ", "&Otilde;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "Ö", "&Ouml;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "Ø", "&Oslash;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "Ù", "&Ugrave;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "Û", "&Ucirc;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "Ü", "&Uuml;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "Ý", "&Yacute;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "Þ", "&THORN;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "ß", "&szlig;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "à", "&agrave;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "â", "&acirc;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "ã", "&atilde;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "ä", "&auml;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "å", "&aring;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "æ", "&aelig;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "ç", "&ccedil;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "è", "&egrave;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "ê", "&ecirc;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "ë", "&euml;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "ì", "&igrave;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "î", "&icirc;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "ï", "&iuml;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "ð", "&eth;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "ñ", "&ntilde;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "ò", "&ograve;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "ô", "&ocirc;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "õ", "&otilde;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "ö", "&ouml;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "ø", "&oslash;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "ù", "&ugrave;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "û", "&ucirc;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "ü", "&uuml;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "ý", "&yacute;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "þ", "&thorn;")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "ÿ", "&yuml;")
    EncodeString = strTemp
End Function
```

Comment: I was going for something like this, but I was hoping I could find something more efficient or more 'cute'. Plus, it's easy that way to forget some, as I can see in this one since the ' is not there.

Comment: Another option would be loading them from a file which would make the code cleaner, but it would also be far less efficient. Similarly, having them stored in some kind of array and then looping through the array would look nicer in the code, but also be more memory-intensive.

Comment: Ah well. This solution will do :) . I guess it was naive of my part to believe Acess could have already implement it.

Comment: That's a bad practice, all symbols should be written as `ChrW(i)` in the code, take for instance pound symbol, on my PC it will be converted to "Ł" when I paste the code to my VB Editor. Besides the list is very short, where is &euro; &trade; and other most popular entities?

Answer (score 3):

Question answered, but I would like to say something too.
If you would, you can generate hex based html entities quickly.
It's easier this way to not have know the entity name.

```
Function EncodeString(ByVal strOriginal)
    Dim currChar, i, sOut, CharList
    CharList =  "óáéíúÁÉÍÓÚ¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿×÷ÀÂÃÄÅÆ" &_
                "ÇÈÊËÌÎÏÐÑÒÔÕÖØÙÛÜÝÞßàâãäåæçèêëìîïðñòôõöøùûüýþÿ"
    sOut = strOriginal
    For i = 1 To Len(CharList)
        currChar = Mid(CharList, i, 1)
        sOut = Replace(sOut, currChar, "&#x"& Hex(AscW(currChar)) &";")
    Next
    EncodeString = sOut
End Function
```